# How to filter mysql data on JSON with multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have 10 + checkboxlist under 5 category. I want to display result depends on the user selected checkbox with JSON from MYSQL. My html code is

```
<h1>Filter</h1> 
<form action="filter.php" method="post"> 
   <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Filter by brand</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" Samsung "> Samsung</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" Apple "> Apple</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nokia "> Nokia</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" HTC "> HTC</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="  OnePlus"> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
      </div>


      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Price Filter</div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Below ₹5,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹10,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹15,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹20,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹25,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹35,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹40,000</option>
            <option>Above ₹40,000</option>
        </select>
```

```
      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Operating System</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Android</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> iOS</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Asha OS</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> S40 / Symbian</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Windows Phone</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Blackberry OS</label><br>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Display</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display" > Below 4 inches</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display"> 4 inches to 5 inches</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display"> 5 inches to 6 inches</label><br>
    </div>
```

RAM

```
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram[]" value="512 "> 512 MB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram[]" value="1 "> 1 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram[]" value="2 ">  2 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram[]" value="4 "> 4 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram[]" value="8 "> Above 4 GB</label><br>
      </div>

</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
</form>
```

I want to filter data with JSON. Should i use if condition for all combination or there is any other solution ?

Comment: You could use a table with names and loop through that.

Comment: Can you show me a sample code ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. You have your fields, They have names. Put them in an array and run over that.